# How to generate a TextView inside a thread inside a for loop in the main activity

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to generate a TextView inside a for loop in the main activity? I have to run a thread from another Java class "multithread." When this class runs, I will know how many clients connected to, I will run the insider thread to generate TextViews according to the number of the clients, and display the received messages in these TextViews.

But I am obtaining an error. If you know any better way to run a thread inside the main activity, please let me know, thanks.

Here is the method:

```
public void toggleButtonConnectToClientsFunction(View view) {
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Multithread here
                    multicastthreadRun.run();
                    for(int counter=0;counter<multicastthreadRun.ClientIpArrayList.size();counter++) {

                        TextView textView=new TextView(this);//i am obtaining error here
                        linearLayoutSecondaryTexts.addView(textView);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //in this case we can change the user interface



                        }
                    });
                    }//end of the for loop
                }
            });t.start();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Runnable` is an anonymous class and `this` is pointing to that anonymous class. To create a textview, you need to pass `context` (either activity or context) so in order to do that, use specific reference to class with `className` as

```
TextView textView=new TextView(YourContainerActivityClassName.this);
// e.g     TextView textView=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

Note: since it's a click listener so seems like this is in an activity directly

and you cannot update the UI from worker threads so do it like

```
public void toggleButtonConnectToClientsFunction(View view) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Multithread here
                multicastthreadRun.run();
                for(int counter=0;counter<multicastthreadRun.ClientIpArrayList.size();counter++) {

                    // use proper context
                    TextView textView=new TextView(YourActivityNamethis);//i am obtaining error here

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Update UI
                        linearLayoutSecondaryTexts.addView(textView);
                    }
                });
                }//end of the for loop
            }
        });t.start();

}
```

Comment: `TextView` constructor need `Context` object which means `getBaseContext()` is sufficient, and your solution is correct for sure.

Comment: @Pavneet thanks so much,i am going to get data continuously from the client side and represent it in that textview,so in this case, it's not suitable?

Comment: continuous data transfer connections, sounds you should go for socket programming or maybe `sync adapters` or maybe something similar to firebase updates with listeners

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yes i am using java socket and the program is working fine in the pc and now i have to but the server side code in android,i created 2 thread inside each other, the multicast thread to get the connection with the clients in the network then the unicast to receive the data coming from the client...should i do the same in android or i have to do something else

Comment: @KamelK you can do the same in android , if your app is running then you just need to worry about the memory and UI updation though there are many libs available for socket programming like socket.io etc

Answer (score 2):

> TextView textView = new TextView(this);//i am obtaining error here

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getBaseContext());// textview expect context object NOT runnable object.
```

**And instead of using loop you can just use Recursion.**

```
public void toggleButtonConnectToClientsFunction(View view) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Multithread here
            multicastthreadRun.run();
            makeTextView ( 0,multicastthreadRun.ClientIpArrayList.size());
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private void makeTextView(final int count, final int max){
    if (count>= max)
        return; // end of Loop

    TextView textView = new TextView(getBaseContext());// Use can you this here as it will refer to your activity object.

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //in this case we can change the user interface
         linearLayoutSecondaryTexts.addView(textView);
         makeTextView(count+1, max);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `TextView(this)` will not work because it is inside on Thread.

You have to specify the context exactly. Check below code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
tv.setText("What to do");
```

Thanks :)